# How do I correctly use Microsoft flow conditionals with a YES/NO Columnin A sharepoint list?

Tags: microsoft-flow

I have a Sharepoint list that I have created for testing purposes only. What I am testing is sending an email with different content based on a conditional in a Microsoft-flow process. The conditional looks at a Yes/ No column called Test_YES_NO_DEFAULT_YES. As the name implies, that column always sends back a YES. The process works fine, but the conditional always sends back the IF NO in the email. This is what the flow looks like! 
[image]
I have had tried 1, True, TRUE, true, yes, Yes, and YES with no results. What do I have to do In order for the conditional to execute the IF YES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that currently this can only be done in "advanced mode".
Enter this formula:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['Test_YES_NO_DEFDAULT_YES'], true)
```

Note that this is not the same as you tried (true), since writing "true" in Basic mode puts the string in the formula, instead of the bool value `true`.

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner!

Comment: :) Glad I could help!

Comment: Any chance you know some good documentation or tutorial videos on this topic? Going to Microsoft wasn't to much help on this topic. basically, they promote this tool for twitter and stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately no.. I haven't had chance to do any serious work with flow so far. It looks promising, but we'll see how it will behave in real world scenarios (other than creating a tweet or facebook entry :) )

Comment: If you want to know how this one scenario went for me; I found that it does not always send emails (3:4 ratio actually sending it). do keep in mind that I did **not** purchase the other models. I am using the free version. also, I do believe there a couple of ways of sending emails. Such as _gmail_ and _outlook_. So maybe those two options or more reliable

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know. I tried about 10 times and it had sent an email every time (I have E3 plan).

Comment: yea, that's probably the reason why!